# How to download image file with unknown length on android

Tags: android, image, http, download, inputstream

I'm trying to display file from local network url

```
http://192.168.1.118:1881/image.jpg
```

and display it immidiatelly in ImageView. Problem is that when I open inputStream for this url and try to decode it with BitmapFactory I get null Bitmap. I suppose that is because I get this message from input stream: libcore.net.http.UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.

That image is supported and hosted by server app which I can't modify.

Thanks very much, I've tried hard and looked for solutions, but nothing works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download it to a byte array and decode the byte array:

```
byte[] data = read(inputStreamFromConnection);
if (data != null) {
    Bitmap downloadedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
}

public static byte[] read(InputStream is) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8192);
    try {
        // Read buffer, to read a big chunk at a time. 
        byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
        int len;
        // Read until -1 is returned, i.e. stream ended.
        while ((len = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "File could not be downloaded", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Input stream could not be closed.
        }
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Download now works. I mean there is a lot of stuff in data array. But trying to decode it via BitmapFactory still doesn't work. It returns null :(

Comment: Strange. I tried out the code now and it works flawlessly on a random image URL on the net. Could you paste the URL of your image in a browser, to make sure it's actually displayed in the browser? It might be a corrupted jpeg. Maybe try with another URL on the net? Also, make sure you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the full image, then show it after the download is completed. For example, write *all* the downloaded bytes to an array then use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`. Or save the image to a temporary file, then use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` and then delete that file.